# Spark Streaming Continuous Job

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job that implements a custom receiver.  This receiver gets records from a queue until the queue is exhausted (or an interval is met)  before returning those records to the host context to be written to a database.

Once these records are written, I want the host process to fire up a new receiver and continue processing,  how do I do this with the API?

The host process looks like this:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val config = new SparkConf()
  config.setAppName("Vehicle Data Queue Consumer")
  config.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

  val streamContext = new StreamingContext(config, Seconds(1) )

  val rStream = generateReceiverStream(streamContext)

  val sparkContext = new SparkContext(config)

  streamContext.start()

  streamContext.awaitTermination()
}

def generateReceiverStream(aContext: StreamingContext): ReceiverInputDStream[List[String]] = {

  val rmqReceiver = new RMQReceiver("amqp://myQueue")
  val customReceiverStream = aContext.receiverStream(rmqReceiver)

  val handler = (rdd: RDD[List[String]]) => this.handleStreamResult(rdd)

  customReceiverStream.foreachRDD(handler)


  return customReceiverStream
}

def handleStreamResult(rdd: RDD[List[String]]): Unit ={
  rdd.foreach { record =>
    record.foreach { aString =>
      println("****************************")
      println(s"$aString")
      println("****************************")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can find something here: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/

Comment: What would you like to happen after the data is received? Not sure I understand what you mean with "I want the host process to fire up a new receiver and continue processing"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Receivers are instantiated once at the start of the streaming context and are expected to be 'alive' while the Spark Streaming job is active. Spark Streaming will use the `onStart()` and `onStop` methods on the receiver to manage its lifecycle.

In Spark Streaming, `receivers` should concurrently produce data while active. That is after the invocation to `receiver.start()` a custom receiver should create and manage their own threads where calls to `store(...)` will produce data for the logical DStream created from this receiver.

Spark Streaming will manage the receiver lifecycle to handle failure scenarios and the `streamingContext.stop` calls. It's therefore not necessary or even possible to 'fire up a new receiver' programmatically after the streaming context has been started.

Design and implement your custom receiver to follow this expected behavior and the job will run continuously without any further effort.

Comment: THis was the answer to my question, the receivers should manage their own connections, not the job that spawns them.  Thanks.

Also, for people with similar questions, foreachRDD runs continually, and event receipts are treated like events